# find latest value across rows for columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with data as below.

```
compid  manualscandate  staticscandate  dynscandate
1       1-Aug-12    3-Aug-12    2-Aug-13
1       2-Aug-12    2-Aug-12    3-Aug-12
1       3-Aug-12    1-Aug-12    1-Aug-12
2       1-May-12    3-May-12    2-May-13
2       2-May-12    2-May-12    3-May-12
2       3-May-12    1-May-12    1-May-12
```

i need to find the latest dates for each compid.. such that .. the output table is

```
compid  manualscandate  staticscandate  dynscandate
1       3-Aug-12    3-Aug-12    3-Aug-13
2       3-May-12    3-May-12    3-May-12
```

what is the best way to get this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group around the `compid` then you can use aggregate functions like `max()` to collect the data you want

```
select compid, 
       max(manualscandate) as manualscandate, 
       max(staticscandate) as staticscandate, 
       max(dynscandate) as dynscandate
from your_table
group by compid
```